# Accessing Ubuntu's password store using C++

Tags: ubuntu-one, c++

I'm trying to write an application in C++ that uses the Ubuntu One OAuth token stored in the Gnome Keyring, but I can't find any documentation on either the Gnome or Ubuntu One developer sites that tell me how to do this.

The Ubuntu One site says that all requests to the Ubuntu One service must be signed with a valid Ubuntu One OAuth token, but it doesn't say how to go about this.

The Gnome API reference for the Keyring API simply runs off a list of functions without any context or, more importantly, the `#include` directive that I'm supposed to use to get those functions into my program.

Does anyone know where I can find any documentation that helps me access the Ubuntu One OAuth token?

Comment: Yeah, I've tried. I've been working on this problem for weeks now and am getting nowhere with it.

Comment: Do you think, then, that it may not be possible? Note I'm not a dev for either C++ or Ubuntu One, but i think that if there's no information on it, then there may not be a solution at the moment.  Especially if there's absolutely NO documentation :P

Comment: The problem isn't that there is _no_ documentation, it's that what there is isn't fit for purpose. It's all been written as a reference manual rather than as teaching material for people unfamiliar with the platform, not to mention being fragmented across multiple projects (three in my case, Ubuntu One, Desktop Couch and Gnome).

Comment: Sometimes there are man pages for C(++) functions, maybe you can do a `man 2 <yourfunction>` and see in which header files it is.

Comment: http://live.gnome.org/GnomeKeyring Have you tried the docs under the "saving passwords" section?

Comment: FYI Chris: Documentation in its nature doesnt need to be teaching, it can just describe what functions do :P  Read the Sun Java API which is Java's programming documentation, that's what you get xD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There may be no documentation. But there are sources and examples. There are a couple of C programs which use ubuntu one that you can use as guides.

You can try to run the following (if your repositiories include sources of course):

```
apt-get source libubuntuone
```

Followed by

```
sudo apt-get build-dep libubuntuone
```

and check out the sources. I believe this might be of interest. On `u1-music-store.c`, line 229.

```
static void
get_credentials (U1MusicStore *music_store,
                 gchar **oauth_consumer_token,
                 gchar **oauth_consumer_secret,
                 gchar **oauth_token,
                 gchar **oauth_token_secret)
{
        SyncdaemonCredentials *credentials;

        *oauth_consumer_token = *oauth_consumer_secret = *oauth_token = *oauth_token_secret = NULL;

        /* Get the OAuth token from the keyring */
         if ((credentials = syncdaemon_authentication_find_credentials (
                      syncdaemon_daemon_get_authentication (music_store->priv->syncdaemon)))) {
                *oauth_consumer_token = g_strdup (syncdaemon_credentials_get_consumer_key (credentials));
                *oauth_consumer_secret = g_strdup (syncdaemon_credentials_get_consumer_secret (credentials));
                *oauth_token = g_strdup (syncdaemon_credentials_get_token (credentials));
                *oauth_token_secret = g_strdup (syncdaemon_credentials_get_token_secret (credentials));
         }
}
```

The library you are looking for is libsyncdaemon-1.0-dev. At least on 10.10. As far as I can see, you don't need the keyring API from gnome.